# Writing Multiple Lines of User Input to a File

Tags: java

I am trying to have the equivalent of a text box in console by reading the user's input until a certain terminator sequence is reached, but I cannot figure out how to get it to terminate.

Here the code that is supposed to read input and write it to the file:

```
try {
    out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("outagain.txt");
    userInput = new Scanner(System.in);

    String input;
    while ((input = userInput.nextLine)) != null) {
        out.write(input);
        out.newLine();
        input = null;
    }
} finally {
    if (userInput != null)
        userInput.close();
    if (out != null)
        out.close();
```

Is there some way I can capture an escape "code" from the user (i.e. they write ":END" which breaks out of the loop) or is there another way to do it?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Yes, you can do it by setting up some termination word like `:END` .

Comment: How would I do it then? I tried it but the loop wouldn't terminate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by comparing each input line with the specific termination word.
Suppose the termination word is `:END` then we can check each input line with the `termination word`.

If we find that termination word as an input , We will break the loop and stop taking the input from user and close the `BufferedReader` as well as the `Scanner`.

**Sample Code:**

```
    try 
    {
        out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("outagain.txt"));
        userInput = new Scanner(System.in);

        String input = userInput.nextLine();    //Store first input line in the variable
        String Termination_Word = ":END";
        while(!input.equals(Termination_Word))  //Everytime Check it with the termination word.
        {
            out.write(input);                   //If it isnot a termination word, Write it to the file.
            out.newLine();
            input=userInput.nextLine();         //Take other line as an input.
        }
    } 
    finally 
    {
        if (userInput != null)
            userInput.close();
        if (out != null)
            out.close();
    }
```

Comment: I am a little disappointed in my self for not thinking of that... oh well. Thank you for the help.